# Is gcc's atomic test and set builtin the same as an atomic fetch and store operation?

Tags: gcc, atomic, built-in, test-and-set

I came across an atomic "fetch and store" instruction in the description of an MCS lock.

From what I gather, this atomically writes a value to a memory location and returns the original value of that memory location, is that correct?

And is gcc's atomic builtin,

```
   __sync_lock_test_and_set
```

the same as an atomic fetch and store?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [GCC info page](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html#Atomic-Builtins), this is indeed atomic, but it's not the basic atomic fetch and store.

(this is clipped from the 4.4 manual, so different section number)

> ## 5.48 Built-in functions for atomic memory access
>
> (...)
>
> ```
> TYPE __sync_fetch_and_add (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_fetch_and_sub (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_fetch_and_or (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_fetch_and_and (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_fetch_and_xor (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_fetch_and_nand (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_add_and_fetch (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_sub_and_fetch (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_or_and_fetch (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_and_and_fetch (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_xor_and_fetch (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> TYPE __sync_nand_and_fetch (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> bool __sync_bool_compare_and_swap (TYPE *ptr, TYPE oldval TYPE newval, ...)
> TYPE __sync_val_compare_and_swap (TYPE *ptr, TYPE oldval TYPE newval, ...)
> __sync_synchronize (...)
> TYPE __sync_lock_test_and_set (TYPE *ptr, TYPE value, ...)
> void __sync_lock_release (TYPE *ptr, ...)
> ```

They're apparently taken from the Intel Itanium reference manual, but GCC implements them on any CPU they can be (and warns if you use one on a CPU that doesn't, then uses a non-atomic version).  The function you noted is actually an extended memory barrier (or critical area):  the barrier is established by `__sync_lock_test_and_set`, and released by `__sync_lock_release`.

If you're looking for a basic atomic fetch-and-set, it's probably `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` although in most cases you'll want to use one of the more specific versions.

Comment: Are you sure you can implement a fetch_and_store with a compare_and_swap?

Comment: @GaetanoMendola: A compare_and_swap retry loop can implement *any* atomic RMW on a single variable.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap .  A single CAS can implement TAS on a bool, like `val.CAS(0, 1)` to try to change it from 0 to 1, with success on the CAS meaning the old value was 0, failure meaning it was already set.  (Or with the obsolete GNU C `__sync` builtins, you can use `__sync_var_CAS` instead of `__sync_bool_CAS` to get the old value directly like you want for TAS.